# Contact Form 7 Check for Empty fields with PHP

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've got a contact form 7 form that I'm looking to execute php in the Message Body. Here i try to check is empty `[company_name2]` or `[zip-code-emp2]` or `[street_emp2]` or `[city_field_emp2]` . If one of them is not empty, them i must show paragraph with this information, if they are empty, they must do not sent in Message Body. Can i check this in Message Body or i must create function in function.php and how to send email from this function?

Comment: You can make them required in the form, isn't that a good option for you?

Comment: no, this fields are not required. in the e-mail i have label before field and after label text from field ... how to remove label and field if field is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox in cf7 (on the mail panel) under the textarea where you define your mail. I think it's called 'Exclude lines with blank mail tags'.

I think that should work for you.

Comment: i know for this checkbox, but i must remove and label before empty field ... then they are checked the label is there

Comment: What do you mean by 'I must remove and label before empty field'?... I don't understand your problem so It's hard for me to help :/